# Spring BeanFactoryPostProcessor and lifecycle issues

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

I have a Spring MVC App (3.2.9) running on a large number of servers, it failed to deploy to a proportion of those servers today with an auto wiring problem, no matching bean of type error. The problem isn't repeatable in local development environment.

The App uses quite a range of annotations such as @Configuration, @Bean, @Autowired, @Service etc

There was a new @Configuration class and @Bean method added, and the Bean was to be injected into a constructor of a class annotated with @Service. Rolling back to a previous version of the code worked ok, so it does seem like the new @Configuration class isn't being processed probably. It's a weird issue. I want to avoid a repeat performance on production - so would like to understand what happened

Could this problem be a race condition related to BeanFactoryPostProcessor lifecycle issues documented in the Spring API for the Bean Class - as detailed below (application uses PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer but it's not yet configured as a static method)?

```
    No qualifying bean of type [..removed...] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [..removed...] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver in createArgumentArray at line 752application
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver in autowireConstructor at line 193application
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory in autowireConstructor at line 1075application
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory in createBeanInstance at line 979application
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory in doCreateBean at line 487application
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory in createBean at line 458application
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1 in getObject at line 296application
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry in getSingleton at line 223application
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory in doGetBean at line 293application
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory in getBean at line 194application
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory in preInstantiateSingletons at line 633application
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext in finishBeanFactoryInitialization at line 932application
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext in refresh at line 479application
    org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader in configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext at line 410application
    org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader in initWebApplicationContext at line 306application
    org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener in contextInitialized at line 112application
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext in listenerStart at line 4994application
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext in startInternal at line 5492application
    org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase in start at line 150application
    org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase in addChildInternal at line 901application
    org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase in addChild at line 877application
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost in addChild at line 649application
    org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig in deployWAR at line 1083application
    org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar in run at line 1879application
```

From Spring Documentation on Bean class...

> Special consideration must be taken for @Bean methods that return Spring BeanFactoryPostProcessor (BFPP) types. Because BFPP objects must be instantiated very early in the container lifecycle, they can interfere with processing of annotations such as @Autowired, @Value, and @PostConstruct within @Configuration classes. To avoid these lifecycle issues, mark BFPP-returning @Bean methods as static. For example:

```
 @Bean
 public static PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ppc() {
     // instantiate, configure and return ppc ...
 }
```

> By marking this method as static, it can be invoked without causing instantiation of its declaring @Configuration class, thus avoiding the above-mentioned lifecycle conflicts. Note however that static @Bean methods will not be enhanced for scoping and AOP semantics as mentioned above. This works out in BFPP cases, as they are not typically referenced by other @Bean methods. As a reminder, a WARN-level log message will be issued for any non-static @Bean methods having a return type assignable to BeanFactoryPostProcessor.

Ok, an update, there are 116 servers, and for some reason the bean was only created on 67. Changes were made to following didn't make much of a different

```
public static PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ppc()

@Configuration
public class BlahClientConfig {

    @Bean
    public BlahClient blahClient() throws URISyntaxException {
        try {
            BlahClientFactory factory = new BlahClientFactory();
            return factory.create();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Failed to create blahClient",e);
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible that multiple component-scan entries are causing problems (legacy code)

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.blah.a.b.c"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.blah.d.e.f"/>
<bean class="com.blah.config.MetricsConfig"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.blah.a.h.config"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.blah.a"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.blah.f.g.h.i"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="
    com.blah.core.common,
    com.blah.core.domain,
    com.blah.core.shared,
    com.blah.core.spec.impl.legacy,
    com.blah.api.client.impl,
    com.blah.common.util.time"/>
<context:annotation-config/>
```

Anyone got any clues?

Comment: What's your exception?

Comment: On a related issue @Autowired(required = false) on Constructor doesn't seem to work

Comment: I've lost confidence in Spring DI.. Started to dig into the code and debug what's going on.. Time for Spring to start again imo

Comment: never got to bottom of this.. app was switched to jetty and issue seems to have gone away. seems like a class loading issue on tomcat of some sort